# Formato de fecha cambia a ingles Reporting Service

Tags: datetime, ireport

Tengo un reporte el cual muestra en su contenido la fecha de un calculo, el cual deberia tener formato en español, ej: 22 de Marzo 2017; Sin embargo se muestra en ingles: 22 MARCH 2017. Cuando reviso el dataset que me obtiene tiene el siguiente formato:
dd' de 'MMMM' 'yyyy

y region El Salvador. Sin embargo continua mostrando la fecha en formato ingles al menos el MES pero deberia ser en español.

De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Consideraciones de diseño de soluciones para las implementaciones plurilingües (Reporting Services) o globales](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms156493.aspx)

> **Idioma de los informes:** Para invalidar el formato proporcionado por el idioma del servidor de informes, puede establecer la propiedad `Language` en el informe al diseñarlo. Puede establecerse en el nivel de informe o en el nivel de TextRun.
>
> Si desea variar el formato basado en el idioma o configuración regional del explorador o aplicación cliente, puede establecer la propiedad `Language` en una expresión que incluya la variable `User!Language`.

---

Para solucionar tu problema solo sería definir en las propiedades:

```
Formato:  dd' de 'MMMM' 'yyyy
Language: es-SV
```

[image: Configuración definida para idioma específico del reporte]